# Broken Pip (Gentoo)

Tags: python, gentoo, pip

I've been trying to figure out how to set up a Matrix server with Synapse. It was working fine, but somehow it broke. Was following a few different guides so I'm not sure exactly how it broke. I'm not experienced with Python/pip at all so I figured someone with more Python knowledge could help me out.

Running synapse_homeserver gives `Synapse 1.79.0 needs Jinja2>=3.0, but got Jinja2==2.11.3`, even though `dev-python/jinja-3.1.2` is installed through Portage.

I also tried setting up a virtual environment (which hopefully I did right). Jinja2 3.1.2 installs just fine with pip, but I still get the same error. Is there some way to reset the pip configuration back to stock, or is there another way to fix this? I don't want to accidentally mess up Python or pip as that would render Portage useless (also known as a Bad Thing™). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple version of `Jinja` installed and `Synapse` is picking up the older version. Lets use a Python virtual environment to isolate your `Synapse` installation.

first, if you havent install `virtualenv` `pip install --user virtualenv` then we create a new env `virtualenv synapse-venv` then we activate it `source synapse-venv/bin/activate` then we install `Synapse` `pip install matrix-synapse` then we can run Synapse `synapse_homeserver`

Remember to activate the `virtualenv` when you want to do that.